# Как изменить источник изображения при наведении?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, вёрстка

Я хочу изменить источник изображения с помощью jQuery, но с анимацией.

У меня начальное изображение по умолчанию и  есть 5 разных изображений с головой, смотрящей в разные стороны. При наведении курсора на определенное маленькое изображение вверху, я хочу изменить исходное, большое изображение на это конкретное значение src изображения.

Если ни на один div нет  `:hover`, должно быть исходное изображение по умолчанию.

Я добился этого, но изображения должны меняться с анимацией. Мои анимации мерцают.

Может ли кто-нибудь указать мне правильное решение, без мерцания?

```js
$('#thumbs img').hover(function(event) {

  $(this).fadeOut(100, function() {
    var thisSRC = $(this).attr('src');
    $('#main').attr('src', thisSRC);
  }).fadeIn(100);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="thumbs">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/rxX8VMq/left.png" width="50" height="50">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/r77CrCC/topleft.png" width="50" height="50">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/CzRdRtp/top.png" width="50" height="50">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/L8cSs3p/topright.png" width="50" height="50">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/D1cjqfD/right.png" width="50" height="50">
</div>

<img id="main" src="https://i.ibb.co/3dMWhqV/default-head.png">
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to change an image source on hover?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56586446/7394871) от участника  [@Mohammed Wahed Khan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8040185/mohammed-wahed-khan).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/56586446/7394871

Comment: Посмотрите, может у кого получится сделать решение плавного перехода от одного изображения к другому без дискретного рывка

Answer (score 2):

Учитывая тот факт, что вы уже используете полноразмерные изображения, тогда можно использовать решение только на CSS, поскольку для загрузки больших изображений не требуется дополнительной пропускной способности:

### Решение только CSS

```css
.thumb{ 
  width: 50px; 
  display: inline-block;
}

.thumb:hover  ~ .big .default{ opacity:0; }


.thumb:nth-child(1):hover ~ .big > img:nth-child(1){ z-index:5; opacity:1; }
.thumb:nth-child(2):hover ~ .big > img:nth-child(2){ z-index:5; opacity:1; }
.thumb:nth-child(3):hover ~ .big > img:nth-child(3){ z-index:5; opacity:1; }
.thumb:nth-child(4):hover ~ .big > img:nth-child(4){ z-index:5; opacity:1; }
.thumb:nth-child(5):hover ~ .big > img:nth-child(5){ z-index:5; opacity:1; }

.big{ position:relative; } 
.big img{ 
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .2s .1s ease-out;
}

.big .default{ opacity:1; }
```

```html
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/rxX8VMq/left.png" class='thumb'>
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/r77CrCC/topleft.png" class='thumb'>
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/CzRdRtp/top.png" class='thumb'>
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/L8cSs3p/topright.png" class='thumb'>
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/D1cjqfD/right.png" class='thumb'>

<div class='big'>
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/rxX8VMq/left.png">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/r77CrCC/topleft.png">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/CzRdRtp/top.png" class='default'>
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/L8cSs3p/topright.png">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/D1cjqfD/right.png">
</div>
```

Намного проще сгенерировать приведенный выше CSS с помощью препроцессоров (например, SCSS).

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56587340/7394871) от участника  [@vsync](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104380/vsync).</sub>